# Combine 2 JS functions

Tags: javascript

I have the following 2 JS functions and I need to combine them, 1 after the other. Script 1 loads the DIV, the 2nd script is the animation that I want to play once the div has loaded:

Here is the first:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama();
        // individual element tween examples
        controller.addTween('#container', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#container'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, scale:0, }, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, scale:1}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
        controller.addTween('#container2', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#container2'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, scale:0, }, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, scale:1}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
    });
</script>
```

Here is the second:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.numbers').delay(1).animate({
    'margin-left': '100px'
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    queue: true
});
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fatfrank44/wRfu5/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your problem/what is your question, now? **/Edit:** You seem to access `$.superscrollorama()`, but it was nowhere defiend. **/Edit II:** You have embedded the scripts from GitHub including GitHub's UI! You have to embed the raw scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the info ComFreak, appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to do this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama();
        // individual element tween examples
        controller.addTween('#container', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#container'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, scale:0, }, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, scale:1}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
        controller.addTween('#container2', TweenMax.fromTo( $('#container2'), .25, {css:{opacity:0, scale:0, }, immediateRender:true, ease:Quad.easeInOut}, {css:{opacity:1, scale:1}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}));
        $('.numbers').delay(1).animate({
            'margin-left': '100px'
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            queue: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Luke, this is what I wanted, thank you. I just need the animation to load AFTER the DIV appears on the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately the fiddle is not loading for me, so I don't quite understand what you're asking. It looks like the addTween functions are fading in the two containers. And the animation for that fade in takes 0.25 seconds, so you could just delay the other script by a quarter of a second.

Comment: I'm struggling with the Fiddle too. Your correct, the functions fade in a DIV as the page scrolls then I want the animation (the 2nd function to start). I guess the problem is the animations loads whilst the DIV is set to '0'?

Answer (score 0):

Along with what ComFreek mentioned about you not including the Javascript correctly from GitHub (which I have fixed in JSFiddle), you set scale and opacity both to 0, which makes your divs "disappear" from the screen. If you fix that, then your animation works fine.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRfu5/6/)

```
css: {
    opacity: 1,
    scale: 1,
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, appreciate you help, this fiddle doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to combine the 2 functions so that the 2nd function starts after the first.

Comment: Right, but all your first function does it set opacity and scale to 0, which makes your divs invisible. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah the fist functions sets the opacity to '0' then fades in as the pages scrolls, when the opacity changes to '1' I want the animation to trigger.

Comment: I can't get the opacity to change to 1 to ever see it, to know if the second function runs afterwards or not.

Comment: Must be an issue with JSFiddle, the 1st function only fires when you scroll the page. I guess I need to remove the DIV rather than set the opacity to '0' - It's playing because it's loaded even though you can't see it!